# eclipse c++ cant find windows macros and functions in <window.h> for window application

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, winapi

I'm using eclipse cpp oxygen with MinGw compiler/toolchain.

I've managed to make a window app in visual studio 2017 with the help of a wizard and I've seen some of things that are supposed to go into the program such as the macro "CALLBACK" but i can't find them in eclipse.
I found a tutorial online and all they #included was  but when i include the header  none of the functions/macros are showing up.

**my sourcefile:**

```
/*
 * launch.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 29 Oct 2017
 *      Author: home
 */
#include <windows.h>


int WinMain() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The WinMain entry point is documented with this signature: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx  Not sure, but maybe you can try matching the signature and see if that changes anything.

Comment: There's an example here at the bottom of this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: it just gives syntax errors.i need to be able to use the macros before i can make windows application. @kvr

Comment: @kvr actually the types have gone blue so it may be working. but this is different to the windows app programs i saw before

Comment: thank you ill come back if there is anymore problems @kvr